# updated 20.04 to 22.04 network not showing up sayis it unclaimed

Tags: 22.04, dpkg, dependencies

*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller

```
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:1e:00.0
   version: 15
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fd504000-fd504fff memory:fd500000-fd503fff
```

tried to do add this linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic_5.15.0-52.58_amd64.deb but get this error:
and coz cant get internet to network not even via phone USB cant do fancy apt get update at all

Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic.

(Reading database ... 190584 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic_5.15.0-52.58_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic (5.15.0-52.58) ...
dpkg:
dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic:

linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic depends on linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic | linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-52-generic; however:

Package linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic is not installed.

Package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-52-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic (--install):

dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic

---

Not doing fresh install coz I have valheim server /seeds on that Ubuntu

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` and also: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I broke Ubuntu so more (couldnt boot), so i backed up my valheim servers and clean installed T_T

everything works now ...